# How to load a 'POST' type page into an iframe in Ember?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe, ember.js

I have an old JSP page in my project. I need to include this page into my new page, where my new UI side is complete EmberJS.

Things that I have tried

1. I got the rendered HTML from JSP using an ajax call and try to render with {{{ var }}} handlebar, But there are lots of scripts inside the page. They are not getting parsed or executed.

How can I load the page into an iframe? The page is POST type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden form that point the target to the `iframe`, then trigger the `click()` event on the hidden submit button when document loaded.

**For Example**

```
<form action="YOUR_JSP_URL" method="post" target="myIframe">
  <input id="postToIframeBtn" style="display: none" type="submit" value=" " />
</form>

<iframe name="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
<script>
document.getElementById("postToIframeBtn").click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, try to insert them into DOM inside components `didInsertElement` hook using jQuery.

Do not use `{{{}}}` it only work with HTML inserting.